# View user geotagging does not work

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Im a beginner in Javascript and im trying to make this exemple to work.

Its a simple idea.

Given a position from a user, if the Lat is < them 50 it will send a simple message.

What happens is that the if simply don't work.. why? didi i need to create a new function or put the if inside one one them.?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function initGeolocation()
         {
               if( navigator.geolocation )
                    {
                       // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
                       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );

                    }
              else
                  {
                      alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
                  }

        }

     function success(position)
         {

             document.getElementById('userLong').value = position.coords.longitude;
             document.getElementById('userLat').value = position.coords.latitude
         }

    function fail()
     {
           // Could not obtain location
     }




   </script>    
   </head>

   <body onLoad="initGeolocation();">
       <FORM NAME="rd" METHOD="POST" ACTION="index.html"> 
       User Longitude: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Long" ID="userLong" VALUE=""><br>
       User Latitude : <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Lat"  ID="userLat"  VALUE=""><br>

       <script>
            if (userLat < 50){
           document.write(" Great")
        }
       else { document.write( "Not Great")}
       </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please read the information on Meta about [how to write a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). "This don't work" is not a good title. [Title has been edited since this comment.]

Answer (score 0):

1. You never assign a value to the `userLat` JavaScript variable.
2. You test `userLat` before you've run the Geo Location code.

Put your test *inside* the success function, and test `position.coords.latitude`

Comment: Know nothing is working...

     function success(position)
         {

           document.getElementById('userLong').value = position.coords.longitude;
           document.getElementById('userLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    
    var userLat = document.getElementById('userLong').value;
    
    
    if (userLat < 50){
             document.write(" Great")
         }
          else { 
          document.write( "Not Great")
  }
         }